# Gizmo UI looks too small

Tags: customization, gizmo

In Blender my Gizmo looks like this:

[image]

But everyone else's seems to be like this:

[image]

I don't know what I messed up. I went over Preferences > Themes but only found settings fo Gizmo colors. How can I make my Gizmo big and easy to read like the image shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under User *Preferences > 3D Viewport > Display* you can control the *3D Viewport Axis* gizmo display type.

Three options are available: *Interactive Navigation* (the default), *Simple*, or *Off*.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I need! Accepted & thanks very much.